# Getting a lot of 504 errors when benchmarking AWS ELB, but not EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

first of all, sorry for bad english, I'm not native.

I'm pretty new to AWS but not to web development, I am trying to configure a cloud solution for one of my website who could get a lot of traffic in near future.

Thanks to stack overflow and AWS documentation, I successfully configured my instances, auto-scalling groups, etc, but when testing it with siege, I've got a strange problem :

- benchmarking on the EC2 instance directly with elastic ips work perfectly 100% availability, all is fine
- benchmarking on the ELB works poorly, 90% availability and all is due to 504 errors, but most of the request are answered in less than 2 seconds

There is only one instance in the auto-scalling group attributed to ELB, and it's the one with the elastic ips.

So, I checked on the internet to see that a lot of people had the same problem than me, but unanswered. I tried all the things I found including :

- Checking if ELB healthCheck was working
- Trying to enable ELB stickiness
- Increasing KeepAlive in EC2
- Re-creating ELB

I've been on this problem for 3 hours now, so I tried other things, but can't remember all.
Do someone have an idea ? Could an amazon guy look into it and find a solution ? because the only reason I'm paying more than my previous hoster is to have a good load balancer.

I'm running apache 2.4 with php7-fpm on m3.medium instances

Bonus : Also, I don't know why, but it seems my server slow down way before reaching the 80% cpu utilization that I defined for a new instance to launch. For example, If i launch 1000 concurrents users for 10 minutes, it take up to 20-30 seconds to load a page, but there is never more than 50% cpu usage.

The last information make me think I hit a problem with ELB scaling delay, because I'm launching 1000 concurrents connections, what do you think about it ?

Thanks in advance ! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for people in the same case than me, I accidentaly found a solution doing optimization to my server :

In apache log, I found that I got a lot of  "server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting" error.
I googled it and found some optimisation tricks saying that I should use mpm_worker (I was using mpm_event) for concurrent connexion
So, I enabled mpm worker instead of mpm_event : https://askubuntu.com/questions/524770/apache-enable-worker-mpm
I used those params :
http://oxpedia.org/wiki/index.php?title=Tune_apache2_for_more_concurrent_connections
I also increased keepAlive and KeepAliveMaxConnect, just in case

Now, it's working perfectly fine, my website handle 1000 concurrent connection with a 2s-10s response time, it's up to me to try to reduce it now.

Hope it will help someone else :)